# Automated duplicate check & bcc using Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wrote this JS to send email automatically using Google Script into a spreadsheet.
Unfortunately, the duplicate check is not working, and the bcc line trigger an error. 
Actually I want to send an email only for the LAST answer into the spreadsheet everytime. 
Could you help me?

```js
var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";

function sendEmails2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  
  var numRows = active;   
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 14)
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var name = row[2]; 
    var surname = row[3]; 
    var salesRepEmail = row[4]; 
    var qualityAnalystEmail = "john@doe.com"
    var customerEmail = row[5]; 
    var websiteURL = row[6]; 
    var solution1 = row[7];
    var solution2 = row[8];
    var solution3 = row[9];
    var toResolve1 = row[10];
    var toResolve2 = row[11];
    var toResolve3 = row[12];
    var checkDate = row[13];
    var message = 'Bonjour '+ name + ' ' + surname + ', ' + 'blablabla';
    var emailSent = row[14];     // Third column
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {  // Prevents sending duplicates
      var subject = "Votre Optimisation De Site Mobile pour " +websiteURL;
      MailApp.sendEmail(customerEmail, subject, message, {
        cc: "",
        bcc: qualityAnalystEmail,+ " " + salesRepEmail,
      });
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 15).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the var numRows = active; what is active ?

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I am looking to get the last row with content into it, not the blank ones

Comment: You should take some look at the documentation, it's helpful. To get the last row, simply use the [getLastRow() method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getLastRow())

Comment: Thank you so much, but I am not a developer. I do not know how to replace my current function by GetLastRow(). I replace getRange? dataRange? both? It is not working. I am beginner, please help me @Pierre-Marie Richard

Comment: Could you provide some example of data for dev purpose ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is triggering on bcc line cause you put a extra comma. As seen on the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)), the bcc parameters should be a **string** with

> a comma-separated list of email addresses to BCC

In your cas, you should'nt have:

`bcc: qualityAnalystEmail,+ " " + salesRepEmail`

but:

```
bcc: qualityAnalystEmail + ", " + salesRepEmail
```

which gives:

```
MailApp.sendEmail(customerEmail, subject, message, {
        cc: "",
        bcc: qualityAnalystEmail+ ", " + salesRepEmail
      });
```

(You also put a extra comma after your bcc parameters which is not good)

Comment: The only thing, is I am also looking to avoid the blank emails. I want to send an email only for the last active row of the spreadsheet, which is not working

Comment: You ask for help on the bcc line trigger also. If you want help about what should be the result f your function, you should add some example of your data and what you're looking for, or/and add a sample of your spreadsheet to get a better point of view of your work.

Comment: Hi Pierre-Marie, I did it in comment, have a good day & thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much , Please find below the datas and the script.

I will try to call the variables into the HTML afterwards using Google Scriptlet. For the moment, the simple text is sufficient. It seems to be working like that, but the code is not clean.

[Image Du Tableau](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCFXC.png)

```js
// This constant is written in column O for rows for which an email
// has been sent successfully.
var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";

function testSchemas() { {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = sheet.getLastRow();  
  var numRows = 1;   // Number of rows to process
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 15)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var name = row[2]; 
    var surname = row[3]; 
    var salesRepEmail = row[4]; 
    var qualityAnalystEmail = "xxx@yyy.com"
    var customerEmail = row[5]; 
    var websiteURL = row[6]; 
    var solution1 = row[7];
    var solution2 = row[8];
    var solution3 = row[9];
    var toResolve1 = row[10];
    var toResolve2 = row[11];
    var toResolve3 = row[12];
    var checkDate = row[13]; 
    function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('Index')
      .evaluate();
}

     Logger.log(doGet);
    var htmlBody = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index').getContent(); 
    var message = 'Bonjour '+ name + ' ' + surname + ', ' + 'c\'est avec grand plaisir que je vous écris pour résumer ... - '+solution1+' \n\n- '+solution2+' \n\n- '+solution3+' \n\nMalgré...';
    var emailSent = row[14];     // Third column
    if (emailSent != "EMAIL_SENT") {  // Prevents sending duplicates
     /*MailApp.sendEmail(customerEmail, subject, message, {
        cc: "",
        bcc: qualityAnalystEmail + ", " + salesRepEmail
      }); */
    MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: customerEmail,
    bcc: qualityAnalystEmail + ", " + salesRepEmail,
    subject: 'Résumé De Notre Consultation Du Site Mobile ' + websiteURL,
    htmlBody: htmlBody,
  }); 
}
      Logger.log(name);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 15).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```